# How to host website that uses node-record-lpcm16 package

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming, sox, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to create a react website that uses google speech to text api. In their [docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-streaming-audio)
they suggest using the [node-record-lpcm16](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16) package to send audio stream to the api and translate in Realtime. However the package requires I install [Sound eXchange(sox)](https://sox.sourceforge.net/) tool locally on my computer for it to work. I am wondering if other people who visit the website will also need sox installed on their machines to use the website after I publish it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this [link](https://medium.com/@amanda.k.hussey/a-basic-tutorial-on-how-to-incorporate-speech-recognition-with-react-6dff9763cea5)  help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Although this method does not use google cloud speech it can be an alternative. Unfortunately the web speech api is not supported by all browsers so performance will varry.